# Maximization of information over set of non-injective functions

Tags: information-theory

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be discrete random variables, with $Y$ and $Z$ independent. Does the following equality hold **if $Z$ is independent also of $X$**?
$$
\max_{f_{Y,Z}} \big\{ \ I(X; f_{Y,Z}(Y,Z)) \ \big\} = \max_{f_X, f_Y} \big \{ \ I(X; f_Y(Y), f_Z(Z))  \ \big \}
$$
where the maximization is taken over all **non-injective**, deterministic functions.

P.S.: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426330/maximization-of-information-over-set-of-non-injective-functions) for the inequality version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the classic example of $X,Y,Z$ binary, $Y, Z \sim \mathrm{Bern}(1/2)$ independently, and $X = Y \oplus Z$ - note that in this case $X$ is independent of $Y$ and independent of $Z$ (but not independent of $(Y,Z),$ of course). The only non-injective functions of one bit are constants, so the right hand side is $0$. On the left hand side, we can use the non-injective function $f_{Y,Z}(Y,Z) = Y \oplus Z$ to violate the desired equality.